# Prim's algorithm providing inconsistent results

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, prims-algorithm

I'm implementing Prim's algorithm for finding a minimum spanning tree in a graph. I have implemented it using a `priority_queue` in STL. The issue is that I get a correct MST for some test cases and a wrong one for others.

My input is an adjacency list representation of a graph. The first line of the text file contains the number of vertices in the graph. Each subsequent line contains information about adjacent vertices for a specific graph vertex. Each line starts with the index of the vertex, followed by pairs of numbers that correspond to the indices of neighboring vertices and the weights of the edges connecting them to the current vertex.

The algorithm works correctly for the following test case:

```
9
0 1 4 7 8
1 2 8 7 11
2 3 7 8 2 5 4
3 4 9 5 14
4 5 10 
5 6 2
6 7 1 8 6
7 8 7
```

Meanwhile, it calculates a wrong MST for this graph:

```
9
0 8 18 6 1 4 10 7 7
6 4 6 1 20
4 1 3 7 5
1 3 12
3 8 4 2 9
2 5 2 
8 2 15 5 8
```

My implementation of the algorithm:

```
void MST::getMST() {
    const int n = graph.adjacencyList.size();
    std::vector<bool> visited(n, false);
    std::vector<int> parent(n, -1);
    std::vector<int> key(n, std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    // Start from vertex 0
    key[0] = 0;
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>, std::greater<std::pair<int, int>>> pq;
    pq.push({0, 0});

    while (!pq.empty()) {
        auto [w, u] = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if (visited[u]) {
            continue;
        }
        visited[u] = true;
        if (parent[u] != -1) {
            edges.push_back({parent[u], u});
        }
        for (const auto& [v, weight] : graph.adjacencyList[u]) {
            if (!visited[v] && weight < key[v]) {
                key[v] = weight;
                pq.push({key[v], v});
                parent[v] = u;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A function to read a graph from a file:

```
void Graph::readGraphFromFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream inFile(filename);
    if (!inFile) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open the file: " << filename << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Read vertex count
    inFile >> vertexCount;
    adjacencyList.resize(vertexCount);

    // Read edges
    std::string line;
    std::getline(inFile, line); // Read the rest of the line after vertexCount
    while (std::getline(inFile, line)) {
        std::istringstream lineStream(line);
        int vertex, neighbor, weight;
        lineStream >> vertex;
        while (lineStream >> neighbor >> weight) {
            adjacencyList[vertex].push_back(std::make_pair(neighbor, weight));
        }
    }

    inFile.close();
}
```

```
// Constructor initializes the MST object with the input graph
MST::MST(const Graph& g){
    graph = g;
}
```

A function to save edges of a MST in a file:

```
// Saves the Minimum Spanning Tree edges to a file
void MST::saveToFile(const std::string& filename) const {
    std::ofstream outFile(filename);
    if (!outFile) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open the file: " << filename << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    for (const auto& edge : edges) {
        outFile << edge.first << " -- " << edge.second << std::endl;
    }

    outFile.close();
}
```

Where could I go wrong here?

Comment: Are you *absolutely* certain that your reading and building of the graph is correct?

Comment: I think @molbdnilo is asking the right question. The first test case has vertices in order while the second test case they are not. It would be helpful if you posted a minimal working example to allow others to run the code. It is really challenging to debug by reading a single method which might not even contain the error.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am not, thank you. I edited my question and added those methods too.

Comment: The graph is probably meant to be undirected, but you are in effect treating it as directed. In your adjacency list, you store the fact that `a` is connected to `b` but not that `b` is connected to `a`. It just so happens that, in the first test, the algorithm looks at the vertices in the "right" order and doesn't need to traverse any of the "missing" edges.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Correct, the graph has to be undirected. So the solution is to pass only those tests, where the vertices are in the right order?

Comment: @volia The solution is to make your graph undirected; add both directions to the adjacency list.

Comment: @molbdnilo OK, if I do it this way i.e. add both directions to the adjacency list, I get an error that my graph contains cycles. I have a function that uses DFS to check a graph for cycles before calculating a MST, which cannot be found if a graph has cycles.

Comment: The MST of an undirected graph has no cycles. An undirected graph has trivial cycles by definition, so there is no point in checking.

Comment: Why would it be an error if your input graph contains cycles?  An undirected graph with no cycles is a tree already.